# How can I get and edit NSBundle information in UI testing?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

my project has three targets.

One of them is ui testing target and in `info` tag, I try to change `iOS Target Properties->Bundle versions string, short` to 2.5.0 (the same as main project).

Before I edit, I create `.pch` file and associate it with ui testing target.

In one test file, I log out `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]` details but it shows `CFBundleShortVersionString = "1.0"` and the `CFBundleIdentifier = "com.apple.test.xxxxUITests-Runner"`.

The property `infoDictionary` is readonly.

So my question is, why the log details is different from the ui testing target info and how do I control the version string in ui testing?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]` from UI testing code, it is getting the information from the *Info.plist* inside the UITests folder, rather than the one from inside the main project folder (your app code).

By default, the version is set to 1.0 for your UI tests so this is why you're seeing `CFBundleShortVersionString = "1.0"`.

Your UI test runner app is compiled separately to your app under test, and doesn't have the power to change the internals of the app's code or configuration, unless there's a way of doing that in the UI of your app.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by changing the version number, but if you need to mock changes to the app's internals, using a unit test instead of a UI test might be the way forward.